# How to check data update using API?

Tags: android, rest, api

My Android App uses News API to get news and set it on RecycleView. How can I check new news? 
app should work in the background and immediately updates new posts in View.

Comment: By checking the last item, save it somewhere ( database, file, ...) then when you relaunch the app check if that saved item is same as the last item in your api.

Comment: and how often should i send new query for checking updates?

Comment: it depend's from you, you can do it every hour or at the application launch ...

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb, i can't find examples. Can you help?

Comment: a similiar thing is "indexing from sql database to nosql database", it's not the same thing but it will give you idea how to do it, search for it.

Comment: @JoãoMarcos Yes. I save the published date of the latest news, and every time when i check the latest news i compare that the published date of latest item with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a service that runs every hour (for example) and get the latests News. Its important to save the last access date to push only news in the interval betwen this date and current date.

Pay attention to 4G limits and battery use.

You can use Timer Class to implement this.
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html